# Python adds undesired tabs to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using a script that basically captures HTML elements from HTML files and sends them to a MySQL DB. I use

`title = line.replace("<!--h1-->",'').replace("<h1>",'').replace("</h1>",'')`

for capturing the `H1`. Now, if I run

`print title`

everything is fine. However, if I run

`print 'post_title = %(title)s'%locals()`

then Python consistently seems to add 2 tabs to the start of `title`.

Does anybody know what's causing this and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Python doesn't add anything; the tabs are already there. What does `print repr(title)` tell you is in the value?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: `print repr(title)` returns `\t\ttitle\n`. OK, I get it: the problem is that `line` starts with two tabs and those aren't removed when `title` is captured.

Answer (score 0):

The way to remove whitespace is to use the `strip()` [string method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip).

```
title = line.replace("<!--h1-->",'').replace("<h1>",'').replace("</h1>",'')
print 'post_title = %s' % title.strip()
```

Or, if you know you always have two unwanted tabs at the beginning of the string, just shorten title. The following code replaces title with all but the first two characters of the string.

```
title = title[2:]
```

---

*Edit*

Another way to do this is using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Similar to the `replace` method for strings, the regular expression substitution method could be used to substitute your double tabs (`\t\t`) with an empty string (`''`).

```
import re
title = line.replace("<!--h1-->",'').replace("<h1>",'').replace("</h1>",'')
# Replace two consecutive tabs.
title = re.sub('\t\t', '', title)
```

What makes the `re` module so powerful is that you can even limit your search to the beginning (or end) of the string in question by using the `^` (or `$`) character.

```
title = re.sub('(^\t\t)', '', title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `strip()` on the `title` string:

```
title = line.replace("<!--h1-->",'').replace("<h1>",'').replace("</h1>",'').strip()
print 'post_title = %(title)s' % locals()
```

It's not necessary to use `locals()` in this way; you already have the required variable, so:

```
print 'post_title = %s' % title
```

or

```
print 'post_title = {}'.format(title)
```

would be preferable.